# ng-bootstrap popover dynamic placement

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a bubble graph where bubbles' placement and size is generated dynamically. I want to show a popover with corresponding bubble's details when I click on a bubble. I managed to figure out how to place the popover on the proper side, now I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically place the popover judging by bubble's size. Can anyone help me with that?

A simple abstraction of the case would be something like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from 'ng-bootstrap';



@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }

@Component ({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="div1" placement="right"
        ngbPopover="Whatever" popoverTitle="Popover"></div>
    <div class="div2" placement="right"
        ngbPopover="Whatever" popoverTitle="Popover"></div>
    <div class="div3" placement="left"
        ngbPopover="Whatever" popoverTitle="Popover"></div>
  `,
   styles: [`
    div {
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .div1 {
      top: 400px;
      left: 100px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .div2 {
      top: 400px;
      left: 400px;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
    }
    .div3 {
      top: 400px;
      left: 1000px;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
    }
   `]
})

class AppComponent {}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I want the popover to always place itself with the arrow pointing to the touching the most left or the most right point of the circle.

Comment: You would have to provide _far_ more details, ideally with a reproduce scenario in a plunker. With the info given it would be next to impossible to provide meaningful help...

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I added an abstract code snippet